# How to change the color of Material-UI's Toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I put my `Toggle` button in my `AppBar`, which created an issue because they are the same color when the `Toggle` is selected.

I've tried many different things (as shown below), but have been unable to change it's color.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle'
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

var Style =
{
    palette:
    {
      primary1Color: '#ffffff',
    },
};

class AppBarComp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {muiTheme: getMuiTheme(Style)};
  }

  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});

  render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
      <div>
        <AppBar
          onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
          title="Time Visualizer"
          iconElementRight={
            <Toggle
              labelStyle={{color:'white'}}
              style={{marginTop:'.75em'}}
              label="Toggle Compare"
            />
          }/>

        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          width={250}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
        <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>Settings</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.handleClose}>About</MenuItem>
        </Drawer>
      </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  }
}

AppBarComp.childContextTypes ={
  muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
};
export default AppBarComp;
```

I'm not really sure how I can get to that element to change it's color. using Chrome, I was able to inspect the element and change it's color that way, but have been unable to repeat that with code.

I've also been unable to center the `Toggle` programmatically, but have been able to do it in chrome which makes be believe I'm not high enough in the object?

If that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want change toggle color in 'on mode', you need to update colors in the theme:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  toggle: {
    thumbOnColor: 'yellow',
    trackOnColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

and then use it :)

```
<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
```

You can check here what other theme stuff is used by toggle:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Toggle/Toggle.js

I don't know if that is the only way to do this but it seems to work :)
There might be problem though if some other control uses that color path :/

Changing color of toggle in 'off mode' is easier:

```
<Toggle 
  thumbStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} 
  trackStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }} />
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Could you possibly tell me how you came to this solution so I'll know for next time?

Comment: Comments fields seems too small for what I wanted to write but I'll try the short version:

Opened Toggle.js to check how the styles are applied.

Found sth like `thumbWhenSwitched` that have `backgroundColor`. That was the only field that got sth to do with colors ;)

The value is taken from `toggle.thumbOnColor` and `toggle` is taken from theme (at top of the file it is assigned from `context.muiTheme`).

If that value is taken from `theme.toggle.thumbOnColor` then I tried to change it in the theme itself and it worked :D (same story with `trackWhenSwitched`)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The `thumbStyle` `trackStyle` trick is great! I used this to set the off mode colors to on mode for a toggle switch I have for changing the color scheme on my app. So left is the current color scheme and when you flick the toggle right, it picks up the colors from the new muiTheme that's loaded.

Comment: this makes the whole switch component disappear on iOS.  I'm on "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.0"

Answer (score 5):

```
    import {Switch,makeStyles} from "material-ui/core"
     
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     toggle: {
             width:50,
            '& .Mui-checked': {
               color: '#109125',
               transform:'translateX(25px) !important'
           },
           '& .MuiSwitch-track': {
               backgroundColor:'#008000e0'
           }
       },
    })   

const Index= (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles(); 
       return( 
    <Switch color="primary" size="small" className={classes.toggle} checked: {true}  />)
}
```

Refer to this code and you will get what you need.

Click on this link for more information [Material-Ui/Switch](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do

```
thumbSwitchedStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
```

Example

```
<Toggle
     thumbSwitchedStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
     labelStyle={{color:'white'}}
     style={{marginTop:'.75em'}}
     label="Toggle Compare"
```

Thus, if selected the color becomes grey :)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibALS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const toggleStyles = makeStyles({
      root: { /* … */ },
      label: { /* … */ },
      outlined: {
        /* … */
        '&$disabled': { /* … */ },
      },
      outlinedPrimary: {
        /* … */
        '&:hover': { /* … */ },
       },
      disabled: {},
    }, { name: 'MuiButton' });
```

generates the following class names that you can override:

```
    .MuiButton-root { /* … */ }
    .MuiButton-label { /* … */ }
    .MuiButton-outlined { /* … */ }
    .MuiButton-outlined.Mui-disabled { /* … */ }
    .MuiButton-outlinedPrimary: { /* … */ }
    .MuiButton-outlinedPrimary:hover { /* … */ }
```

To use the code:

```
      function FunctionalComponent(props){
         const toggleClass = toggleStyles();
         
         return (
           <ToggleButtonGroup value={toggleValue} onChange ={handleToggleValueChange}>
              <ToggleButton value="toggleValue1" className={toggleClass.root}>VALUE 1</ToggleButton>
              <ToggleButton value="toggleValue2" className={toggleClass.outlined}>VALUE 2</ToggleButton>
           </ToggleButtonGroup>
         )
      }
```

For more details: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core

Answer (score -1):

The color of the Material-UI toggle is set to primary1Color, which you can over-ride by making a custom theme.
http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

You'd want to make a styles object somewhere (a separate file is probably best) that contains an object like this:

```
{
    palette: {
        primary1Color: '#YOURCOLOR',
    },
}
```

Assuming you import that into your React class as Styles, you'd want to set it as the theme like this:

```
getChildContext() {
        return {
            muiTheme: getMuiTheme(Styles),
        };
    }
```

And

```
YOUR_CLASS.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

Comment: So I've created the object as a constant, and followed the rest of your instructions but am still unable to change the color.

I've updated the questions to show my current code

Comment: Style should just be the object {
  palette: {
    primary1Color: '#00BCD5',
  },
}
You're passing the output of getMuiTheme as a parameter to getMuiTheme

Comment: I edited the code above. I'm not getting any errors, but It's still not changing the color of the toggle :( What am I missing here?